# Complex Number and String comparison

Tags: bash

In a bash script the user enters an 8-digit number after being prompted for input.

```
echo "Enter an 8-digit number."
read NUM
```

After this a function is executed that generates a single-digit random number.

```
main() {
GEN="$(shuf -i 0-9 -n 1)"
echo "$GEN"
}
main
```

What I need to know how to do is, I need the number that is randomly generated to be compared with each individual integer from the user input. So first the 1's place is compared, then the 10's place compared, then the 100's, and so on and so forth until all 8 digits have been compared.

My question is, how can I compare the generated number with a specific place value in the user input and once that number has been matched, make the function compare with the next place value?

(EDIT)

This script is what I need to be able to do with each individual place value in the user input in sequence.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

echo "Enter a 3-digit number."
read Num

main() {

Gen=$(shuf -i 0-999 -n 1)
echo "$Gen"

if [ "$Gen" == "$Num" ]
then
echo "Match found!: $Gen"
sleep 3
clear
exit 0
fi

}


while true
do
main
done
```

Comment: If you're asking how to extract the ith character from a string, bash supports the syntax `${NUM:$i:1}`

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "ith character" please?

Comment: First character: `i=0`, second character: `i=1` and so on

Comment: So if I wanted to compare the generated number with each place value in this number: 12345678, how would I use this syntax?

Comment: Is it for learning purposes or functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bash shell supports the syntax `${s:$i:1}` to refer to the `i`th character of string `s` (strictly speaking, a substring of length 1 starting at position `$i`), so you can do something like

```
Num=13427598

for ((i=0;i<${#Num};i++)); do 

  Gen=$(shuf -i 0-9 -n 1)

  if (($Gen == ${Num:$i:1}))
  then 
    echo "$Gen matches at position $i"
  else 
    echo "$Gen doesn't match"
  fi

done
```

---

If you want to *loop over* random digits until you find a match, you could do something like

```
for ((i=0;i<${#Num};i++)); do 

  while :
  do
    Gen=$(shuf -i 0-9 -n 1)

    n=$((${#Num}-i-1)) # the string index, starting from least significant digit

    if (($Gen == ${Num:$n:1}))
    then
      echo "Matched $Gen at position $((10**i))" 
      break
    fi

  done

done
```

For efficiency, you might want to consider replacing `$(shuf -i 0-9 -n 1)` with `$((RANDOM % 10))` which uses the shell built-in `RANDOM` in place of external function `shuf`, unless you believe that the distribution of integers produced by `shuf` is important to your application: the final script is then

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter a number: " Num

for ((i=0;i<${#Num};i++)); do 

  while :
  do
    Gen=$(shuf -i 0-9 -n 1)

    n=$((${#Num}-i-1)) # the string index, starting from least significant digit

    if (($Gen == ${Num:$n:1}))
    then
      echo "Matched $Gen at position $((10**i))" 
      break
    fi

  done

done
```

and testing it we get

```
$ ./number.sh 
Enter a number: 16283690    
Matched 0 at position 1
Matched 9 at position 10
Matched 6 at position 100
Matched 3 at position 1000
Matched 8 at position 10000
Matched 2 at position 100000
Matched 6 at position 1000000
Matched 1 at position 10000000
```

Comment: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

The extra "if" causes the error.

Comment: Did you run that code before posting?

Comment: I have updated the question to be more clear on what I am asking. I feel like what you have here is close but it is still not what I am looking for. I'll keep testing things in the meantime.

Comment: @Yokai no I ran the correct code ;) - thanks for noticing the extra `if` which I have now corrected, as well as updating with a suggested answer for your modified question

Comment: I have been playing around with this and what you posted works but it only generates for the first place value in the user input.

With the number 12345678, I need it to compare with 1, and then with 2, and then with 3, and then with 4, etc. But what it is doing is printing the first number and just adding a 0 each time instead of matching and ignoring the previous place value. I cannot help but assume I cannot explain clearly enough what it is I am trying to do.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing differently, but I have added a complete self-contained script that you can save and test

Comment: I'll Give an example in an answer post since I can explain more there. This is most definitely necessary for functionality and not for learning per say. I know a great deal of bash and have been coding tools and such for the past 4-5 years. This unique idea that I have, however, I have a lot of trouble finding information on how to go about performing it.

Comment: I am just going to mark your answer as solved since a lot of the moderators on this platform are so damn nit picky. Thanks for trying to help out.

Comment: @Yokai you are free to edit your **question** to clarify your requirements